$E[X|X^2+Y^2] = 0$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normals.
I need to show that $E[X|X^2+Y^2] = 0$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normals. $E[X|X^2+Y^2] = \int \frac{f(x, x^2+y^2)}{f(x^2+y^2)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{x^2}{-2}}dx$. We want to show that $E[-X|X^2+Y^2] = - E[X|X^2+Y^2]$. Notice that $E[-X|X^2+Y^2] = \int \frac{f(-x, x^2+y^2)}{f(x^2+y^2)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{x^2}{-2}}dx$. Then it boils down to showing that $f(-x, x^2+y^2) = f(x, x^2+y^2)$. We can do this by first calculating $f(x^2+y^2)$. However this calculation seems to be lengthy, is there an easier formal way(without using the calculations) to quickly see that $E[X|X^2+Y^2] = 0$ ?
So $f(-x, x^2+y^2) = f(x^2+y^2|-x)f(-x) =x^2f(-x)$ which concludes the proof. I suppose we don't need the fact that $Y$ is symmetric?

$E[X|X^2+Y^2] =E[-X|X^2+Y^2] $ simply besause $(X,Y)$ has same distribution as $(-X,Y)$

Can you please elaborate on that with more details?   @geetha290krm

Apply the definition of conditional expectation. Normal distribution is also not required. Any symmetric distribution will do.

Thanks @geetha290krm! Do we need to show that $(−,^2+y^2)=(,^2+^2)$? Not sure how that's clear from the fact that $(,)$ has same distribution as $(−,)$.

There is no need to use any pdf's.

$E(X^2|X^2+Y^2)$ is more exciting.

Find $ E(X \mid X^2 + Y^2) $ for $X,Y$ independent standard normal

Let $A$ be a Borel set in $\mathbb R$. Then, $\int_ {(X^{2}+Y^{2}\in A)}XdP=\int_ {(x^{2}+y^{2}\in A)}xdF_{X,Y} (x,y)$ and
$\int_ {(X^{2}+Y^{2}\in A)}(-X)dP=\int_ {(x^{2}+y^{2}\in A)}xdF_{-X,Y} (x,y)$. These are equal because $F_{X,Y}=F_{-X,Y}$.  You only need independence of $X$ and $Y$ and the fact that $X$ has  a symmetric distribution.
